# Netlogo: Is there an `all-of` command, simmilar to the `one-of`?

Tags: netlogo

Is there an equivalent of the command `one-of` that does all agents?  So an `all-of` command?  I need my agents to ask specific other agents to sum and report back a value.  The `one-of` command will only randomly select one other agent but I need to select all agents on a list.

**Details:** I need my `household` agents to to ask other `household`agents to sum and report back their `HHwaterUse` value.  Each `household` agent will ask all other agents on their `SocialNetwork` list.  The `SocialNetwork` list is composed of a `Public_ID` values, which is a value that each agent possesses.

**Ex:** So if `household-1` posses a `SocialNetwork` list that looks like `[9126 3495 4197 8771]`, I need all agents with a `Public_ID` value of 9126, 3495, etc to report back their `HHwaterUse` value.

```
    ask households [
     set NetUseSum sum [HHwaterUse] of households with [[Public_ID] of myself = all-of [SocialNetwork] of self]
    ]
```

Comment: Luke's answer is correct, but if you're going to represent a social network, you should be using [links](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#links) instead of lists. That would make for much nicer (and often faster) code. The difficulties you're experiencing now with your list of IDs are only the tip of the iceberg; everything gets awkward and complicated once you start relying on IDs or `who` numbers. NetLogo shines when you rely on direct agent references, agentsets and links. You will be rewarded in the long run if you embrace this.

Comment: are Public_ID values unique to each agent, or are they more like a category indicator. If they are unique to each agent (and for some reason you don't want to use links as Nicolas suggested), then you can work with agentsets instead of lists of identifiers.

Answer (score 2):

The `member?` primitive should work, check out the [dictionary entry](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#member) for details. Here is an example where just a single household checks the sum of its social network's water use:

```
breed [ households household ]
households-own [ Public_ID Social_Network HH_Water_Use]

to setup
  ca
  create-households 10 [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set Public_ID 1000 + random 1000
    set HH_Water_Use 100 + random 50
  ]

  ask households [
    set Social_Network sort [Public_ID] of n-of 4 other households
  ] 
  reset-ticks
end

to sum-social-network

  ask one-of households [
    show ( word "My social network comprises: " Social_Network )
    ask households with [ member? Public_ID [Social_Network] of myself ] [
      print ( word Public_ID " has a water use of " HH_Water_Use )
    ]
    let social_sum sum [HH_Water_Use] of households with [ member? Public_ID [Social_Network] of myself ]
    print ( word "My social network has a sum water use of " social_sum )
  ]

end
```

**Edit:**

Just a note that I agree with Nicolas and Jen above- this is definitely not the best approach. Use their link or agentset suggestions instead if possible.

Answer (score 0):

That worked, Luke C's suggestion of using the `member?` snippet did the trick.  I was able to sum, all at once, the value from the list of agents.

```
let social_sum sum [HH_Water_Use] of households with [ member? Public_ID [Social_Network] of myself ]
```